# Package manager on the Docker Machine default VM?

Tags: linux, docker, apt, docker-machine

I'm developing on OSX using Docker Machine. I used the quickstart terminal to let it create the `default` VM which is extremely minimal:

> In an OS X installation, the docker daemon is running inside a Linux VM called default. The default is a lightweight Linux VM made specifically to run the Docker daemon on Mac OS X. The VM runs completely from RAM, is a small ~24MB download, and boots in approximately 5s.

I want to install dnsmasq, but none of [these instructions](https://www.iceflatline.com/2010/02/how-to-install-and-configure-dnsmasq/) could work. I expect to come across this kind of problem again, so beyond installing dnsmasq I want to have some tool such as `apt-get` to be able to easily install things. With so few commands available I don't know how to get started. I have `curl`, `wget`, `sh`, `git`, and other very basic commands. I don't have any of the following:

```
apt
apt-get
deb
pkg
pkg_add
yum
make
gcc
g++
python
bash
```

What can I do? Should I just download a more complete VM such as Ubuntu? My laptop is not very fast so a very lightweight VM was very appealing to me, but this is starting to seem like a bit much.

Comment: Did you use `docker-machine ssh default` to login to the VM first?

Comment: In general, if you're installing packages in a container after that container's creation, you're Doing It Wrong. Each container should only run one service, and should have nothing except that service itself and direct dependencies (meaning files that are actually required to run that service) installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The docker-machine VM is based on [TinyCore](http://tinycorelinux.net/welcome.html). To install extra packages use `tce` or `tce-load`, the `apt-get` counterpart of TinyCore.

A word of warning, you shouldn't treat the docker-machine VM as a regular VM where you install tons of packages and customize. It's only meant to run containers. It's best to keep it that way.